# Entity Framework Error Trying to Get Row Count in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

When I try to run this code:

```
var qry = ( from v in db.Visits
           where v.VisitorID == visitorID
              && v.IncomingID == incomingID
              && v.ProjectID == ProjectID.GetID()
           select v.VisitorID);

int visits = qry.Count();
```

The qry runs okay but the "int visits = ..." line bombs out with "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetID()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: query doesn't run until you try to execute `Count`.

Comment: ProjectID.GetID() is a problem here, you should write some int variable -> int projectid = PorjectId.GetID(); and then use it in your linq like -> ... && v.ProjectID == projectid ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you are doing wrong, is that `ProjectID.GetID()` can not be **called** in linq to entity, you can call this before your query:

```
var o = ProjectID.GetID();
var qry = (from v in db.Visits
           where v.VisitorID == visitorID && 
                 v.IncomingID == incomingID && 
                 v.ProjectID == o 
           select v.VisitorID);

int visits = qry.Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd been staring at this for the last hour and didn't spot that :(

Answer (score 3):

You can't call custom methods in a query like this.

LINQ to Entities works by building an expression tree in order to convert to a database query. 
It sees ProjectID.GetID() and it has no idea how to translate that into SQL.